# Servlet как правильно писать логику

Tags: java, servlet

Когда используются контроллеры, допустим, в Spring MVC, всю логику обрабатывают не контроллеры, а какие-то сервисы, которые они вызывают.

Когда пишем сервлет и нам необходимо обрабатывать какие-то параметры, где записывать операции над этими параметрами? В самом сервлете или выносить в отдельный класс, который будет работать по принципу контроллер-сервис?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WEB-приложение обычно имеет [трехуровневую архитектуру](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) (3-tier achitecture). Уровень **Presentation** отвечает за взаимодействие с пользователем, уровень **Service / Application / Business** - включает бизнес-логику приложения, уровень **Data / Persistence** - отвечает за работу с внешними источниками данных. Следование данной архитектуре является принятой хорошей практикой построения приложения.

В соответствие с этой моделью, вам нужно вынести бизнес-логику (т.е. логику не связанную с обработкой запроса) в отдельные классы - сервисы, и использовать **Dependency Injection** для доступа к этим классам из сервлета ([простой пример](https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/JBoss-AS7-Docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/guides/developer-getting-started-guide/target/docbook/publish/en-US/html/helloworld.html)).

**Spring MVC** на уровне Presentation использует паттерн [Front Controller](http://javagu.ru/portal/dt?last=false&provider=javaguru&ArticleId=GURU_ARTICLE_81160&SecID=GURU_SECTION_80703). Все запросы поступают в [DispatcherServlet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java) (это сервлет), откуда уже делегируются контроллерам, в соответствие с конфигурацией приложения. Это стандартный паттерн, который вы также можете использовать в своем JEE приложении.

Comment: спасибо. это то, что нужно было.